# (javascript) Calling a method on an object inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am not sure i named the title properly. Let me explain my little problem.

My code snipppet is pretty short:

```
var myArray= new Array([new Date()],[123],[abc]);
var time = myArray[0].getTime()
```

I want the time saved in the object inside the array to be written to the "time" variable.
I just thought this would work but i get an error.

> Uncaught TypeError: myArray[0].getTime is not a function

Apparently i am doing it wrong, but i have no idea what is the problem and how to do it right.

Comment: the matter is you're defining an imbricated arrays (arrays inside array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its inside of another array:

```
var time = myArray[0][0].getTime();
//                   ^^^
```

Working example:

```js
var myArray = new Array([new Date()], [123], ['abc']),
    time = myArray[0][0].getTime();

alert(time);
```

Comment: Thank you, i was a fool on creating an array in array. Was not intended, and i did not realize.

Answer (score 1):

You define array of arrays [[], [], []], so to get date element you should do this:

```
var myArray= new Array([new Date()],[123],['abc']);
var time = myArray[0][0].getTime();
```

Comment: Thank you, i will be more alert on handling arrays in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The code you used creates an array with arrays inside:

```
var myArray= new Array([new Date()],[123],[abc]); // [[new Date()],[123],[abc]]
```

So you would have to call

```
myArray[0][0].getTime()
```

You probably wanted to do

```
var myArray = new Array(new Date(),123,abc); // [new Date(),123,abc]
```

Or simply

```
var myArray = [new Date(),123,abc];
```

As a tip, when you get these errors, try `console.log`ing the variables. You would see the date you expected was actually an array with a single position, and would easily found out the error :)

Comment: "You probably wanted to do" -- haha, yes, what a shame, but you are right. Thank you for explaining.